# Android - Webview loading 2 times each inside onPageStarted and onPageFinished

Tags: android, webview

i got webview when i run the app its loading webview 4 times

```
        onPageStarted x 2 times

        onPageFinished x 2 times
```

i have check by using alert box

here is the code

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        new DownloadTask().execute(url);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(PrintDemo.this).setTitle("URL LOADED").setMessage("URL LOADED - onPageFINISH").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(PrintDemo.this).setTitle("URL LOADED").setMessage("URL LOADED - onPageStarted").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }
```

please help me where i am doing mistake.

thanks

Comment: Does the webpage redirect to another webpage?

Comment: @RobinF NO no page rediect